# Dragging COUNTIF with OR function in Excel while changing criteria

Tags: excel, countif

I'm trying to do a countif across multiple columns to see if a date is less than dates in any number of 10 columns.

I can do this via a simple formula utilizing the OR function in quotations for the criteria

However, I can't drag that down because of the quotations as it won't update the criteria.

Basically I need to know if Q2 is less than any cell in row 2 from G2 to P2, then apply that to another 7000+ rows where the next one would see if Q3 is less than any cell in G3 to P3.

Comment: `=and(countif(G2:P2, "<"&Q2))` then double-click the small square 'fill handle' in the lower right of the selected cell.

Comment: what is the formula that you have written and that cannot be dragged down?

Comment: If you prefer: `=or(countif(G2:P2, "<"&Q2))` also works ;-)

Comment: For some reason neither of these are returning the correct results, though I appreciate the help. The formula I had was =countif(Q2, "<G2 OR H2 OR I2 OR J2 OR K2 OR L2 OR M2 OR N2 OR O2 OR P2") which does return the correct results, but again can not be dragged

Comment: Also fwiw using these with "<Q2" does work, so it seems the "&" is causing an issue...